# Bootstrap tooltip disappearing target

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I have installed Bootstrap and need some help with the JavaScript/jQuery portion of it.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Some tooltip text!">?</a>

 <!-- Generated markup by the plugin -->
 <div class="tooltip top">
      <div class="tooltip-inner">Some tooltip text!</div>
      <div class="tooltip-arrow"></div>
</div>
```

My JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(function ($) {
        $("a").tooltip()
    });

</script>
```

The tooltip works on hover like it should, however, after moving off the element the entire element disappears. Basically you can only hover on it once and then the `a` tag is set to `display:none;`. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. I see a lot of people face this issue so maybe it will help.

I simply downloaded the latest `jquery-1.11.1.min.js` and installed that. After doing so, it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

This is old but I ran into it today on a site, so I'll answer in case it's helpful to someone else eventually...

If you have [prototype.js](http://prototypejs.org/) loaded on the site, then [prototype adds a `.hide()` method to elements](https://github.com/prototypejs/prototype/blob/4494c23749fc667f9a00b1f2d757d478a925002c/src/prototype/dom/dom.js#L317-L345):

```
function hide(element) {
  element = $(element);
  element.style.display = 'none';
  return element;
}
```

jquery's trigger method [mistakes this for an event emitter](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/f997241f0011ed728be71002bc703c7a0d3f01e5/src/event/trigger.js#L130-L148) and calls it to announce that the tooltip has been hidden:

```
elem[ type ]();
```

...thereby hiding the element to which the tooltip is attached.

Best fix is to stop using prototype.js which extends the DOM in ways that aren't compatible with modern standards.

Second best fix, if you can't kill prototype.js, is to avoid using bootstrap tooltips. Browser tooltips work just fine.

If you really need both, you can instrument bootstrap's `tooltips.js` to change the name of the hide event (and the show event while you're there):

```
diff --git a/bootstrap/js/src/tooltip.js b/bootstrap/js/src/tooltip.js
index ee721a1..eca1726 100644
--- a/bootstrap/js/src/tooltip.js
+++ b/bootstrap/js/src/tooltip.js
@@ -81,6 +81,10 @@ const Tooltip = (() => {

+  // Leading underscore on _hide and _show to rename hide/show events. This
+  // is important because prototype.js supplies Element.hide and
+  // Element.show, so if those names are used here, jquery will discover
+  // and call the prototype-supplied methods when .trigger is called.
   const Event = {
-    HIDE       : `hide${EVENT_KEY}`,
+    HIDE       : `_hide${EVENT_KEY}`,
     HIDDEN     : `hidden${EVENT_KEY}`,
-    SHOW       : `show${EVENT_KEY}`,
+    SHOW       : `_show${EVENT_KEY}`,
     SHOWN      : `shown${EVENT_KEY}`,
```

or you can monkey-patch it:

```
!function (Event) {
  Event.HIDE = '_' + Event.HIDE
  Event.SHOW = '_' + Event.SHOW
}(jQuery.fn.tooltip.Constructor.Event)
```

You'll just have to be aware in your own code that the event name changed, in the unlikely case that you're hooking on it.